# Sage for Galois Field

Tags: sage

I have a problem in Galois Field in SageMath. I can't convert a binary to polynomial.

If I have a binary number, 1010101 how do I convert this number in polynomial 1010101 = x^6+x^4+x^2+1.

Comment: Small spelling corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is an inbuilt way (I presume you have already looked also), but you can always do the following:

```
sage: P.<x> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
sage: binString = "1010101"
sage: arrayOfTerms = [0]*len(binString)
sage: binString = binString[::-1] #Flip it so that the first digit corresponds to the constant term
sage: for i in xrange(len(binString)):
....:     arrayOfTerms[i] = (x**i)*int(binString[i])
....:     
sage: poly = sum(arrayOfTerms)
sage: poly
x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1
```